# MySQL - Eliminate rows from query which are found in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

As a security precaution, before allowing a user to deactivate an item, I would retrieve all the item ids that belong to the user, and add them to an array.

Query:

```
"SELECT id FROM items WHERE user_id = ?"
```

However I want to allow the users to deactivate only items which have no bids. So I joined the bids table on the item id but I'm not sure how to eliminate items which have bids from the query.

```
"SELECT i.id
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bids b
ON i.id = b.item_id
WHERE i.user_id = ?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `items` that have no `bids`:

```
where i.user_id = ? and b.item_id is null
```

as `items` without `bids` will contain `null` values in the `bids` part of the table expression created with `left join`.

Comment: Cool. Thank you! (added the Cool just to be able to comment)